# Search and Replace in multiple MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, replace

I have multiple MySQL databases(50+) and I want to replace a string in all of them, is there anyway to search and replace in all the databases?

Server is CentOS and I have SSH root access.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

Instead, you could do something like

```
SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE ", table_schema, ".", table_name, 
                " SET foo = replace(foo, 'this', 'that');")
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE ...
```

to generate the desired 50+ `UPDATE` statements.  Then copy and paste them into the mysql commandline tool.

(Or you could construct a shell script using that.  Or...)